# Is the planned ROS1 to ROS2/DDS bridge available yet?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds, tcpros, udpros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that part of the plan for ROS2 is to support mixed ROS1/ROS2 systems by implementing a bridge module that translates/republishes ROS1 (TCPROS or UDPROS) messages to ROS2 (DDS) and vice versa.

p. 17 of this ROSCON talk provides some context and mentions the idea in passing:
http://roscon.ros.org/2014static/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ROSCON-2014-Next-Generation-of-ROS-on-top-of-DDS.pdf

My question is whether there is a prototype implementation of this bridge module available yet. We are interested in trying it out. We're in the unusual situation that our robot is already committed to using ROS1 for onboard comms and DDS for off-board comms, so this bridge could come in very handy and help our implementation comply with the evolving standard for ROS2/DDS.

Some relevant stuff I already found: I guess rosidl and rosidl_dds packages together can parse ROS IDL .msg/.srv files and produce DDS IDL .idl files. But they don't seem to have auto-generated message converters unless I missed it:

https://github.com/ros2/rosidl
https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_dds

And this overview helped me to understand how the many ros2 repos fit together, but doesn't (yet) answer my question:

https://github.com/ros2/ros_core_documentation/blob/master/doc/source/index.rst

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209904/is-the-planned-ros1-to-ros2/dds-bridge-available-yet?/) by [Trey Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/22547/trey-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-26**:
Afaik: no it hasn't been implemented yet, but I'll leave it to the osrf guys to give you an 'authorative' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this:
https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1